# openBugs error with simple car.normal() model. My mistake or bug?

Tags: winbugs

I try to implement a spatial intrinsic Gaussian Markov random field model (order = 1) in openBugs via the car.normal() distribution. For a regular 3x3 grid it works fine. But if I increase the sample size (say 4x4) I get an error. Why? I am grateful for hints...

Here is a minimal example, that does not work for 4x4 (but for 3x3 it does):

The file "model.txt":

```
model{
   # likelihoood
   for(i in 1:No){ Y[i] ~ dnorm(Z[i], tau) } 

   Z[1:No] ~ car.normal(adj[], weights[], num[], kappa)
   for(k in 1:Nw) { weights[k] <- 1 }      

   # prior
   kappa ~ dgamma(1, 1) 
   tau ~ dgamma(1, 1) 
}
```

And the "data.txt" for a 4x4 grid:

```
list(No = 16,
Y = c(0.67,0.88,0.38,0.1,0.78,0.67,0.25,0.55,0.11,0.85,0.46,0.5,0.47,0.38,0.21,0.97), 
adj = c( 
5,2,
6,1,3,
7,2,4,
8,3,
1,9,6,
2,10,5,7,
6,14,9,11,
4,12,7,
5,13,10,
3,11,6,8,
7,15,10,12,
8,16,11,
9,14,
10,13,15,
11,14,16,
12,15),
num = c(2,3,3,2,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,2,3,3,2),
Nw = 48)
```

I run it in R (other options are possible):

```
require(R2OpenBUGS)
bugs(data="data.txt",
     inits=function(){list(tau=10, kappa=100, Z = rep(c(-.5,.5),8))},
     parameters=c("Z","tau","kappa"),
     model.file="model.txt",
     n.chains=1, n.iter=150, n.burnin=1)
```

The error is:

```
OpenBUGS version 3.2.2 rev 1063
model is syntactically correct
data loaded
model compiled
error for node Z[1] of type SpatialCARNormal.Node first argument Graph18 error pos 260 (error on line 1)
error for node Z[1] of type SpatialCARNormal.Node first argument Graph18
model must be initialized before updating
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before DIC can be monitored
model must be initialized before updating
model must be initialized before monitors used
model must be initialized before monitors used
DIC monitor not set
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "ajd" object is wrong,
for exemple: the 3rd argument has 3 neighbours: 7, 2, 4. But when you look to the 7th argument it doesn't have the 3rd as its neighbour (6,14,9,11)

That must be the problem, I sugest you look at it carefully